# Problem selecting element by name in practice

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyname

I am trying use the getElementsByName() Method but it is not working for me. I cannot select the field I want. This is the page I am trying to select the email field element from. It's a booking form widget and there is an iframe involved - https://supercleaningservicelouisville.com/book-now

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("booking-widget-iframe");
var field = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('booking[email]');

function changeCopy() {
field.placeholder = "hello";
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", changeCopy)
```

```html
<button id = "button">Click</button>

<input class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-email ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" name="booking[email]" ng-model="ctrl.booking.email" ng-change="ctrl.onBookingEmailChanged()" ng-class="{error: ctrl.booking.errors.email}" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email*" type="email" style="">
```

Comment: seems weird to use angular and to use JavaScript to set properties. Why not just set the placeholder with angular?

Comment: Are you running the code after the element is loaded?

Comment: try with this text "booking[email]". Looks like some invisible character is there. I tried copying the text from your website and tried in console and it worked

Comment: Is it because the element is inside iframe?

Comment: Yes the element is inside an iframe. I edited the question and code snippet with what I thought was a solution but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByName` function only accepts the name of the element, not an attribute, classes or anything else...

It then does return HTMLCollection (iterable) that is similar to an array.

The "old school" way is:

```
let field = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("booking")).find(el => el.hasAttribute('email'));
```

But much easier is to do `document.querySelector('booking[email]')`.

---

On a side note...

If you use angular, use it properly and add `ng-click` to change property in scope, that is used as placeholder

```
<input placeholder="{{myPlaceHolder}}">
<button ng-click="myPlaceHolder = 'new placeholder'"></button>
```